POST table with several objects at once
I made a JSON in postman, which works as it should. It posts data with the made controller.
Now i want to make a page with table(s) that a user can submit object(s).
Working controller for submit with json:
@PostMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public void registerNewWrapper(@RequestBody List<Wrapper> wrapper) {

        for (int i = 0; i < wrapper.size(); i++) {
            Bilag bilag = wrapper.get(i).getBilag();
            List<Innslag> innslag = wrapper.get(i).getInnslag();
            bilagService.registerNewBilag(bilag, innslag);
        }

    }

Working JSON-code:
[
    {
    "bilag": {
        "nr": "1" 
    } ,
    "innslag": [
    {
        "belop": "-10",
        "dato": "2023-02-20",
        "motBilagsNr": "33",
        "konto":{ "id":1 }
    }]
},
{
    "bilag": {
        "nr": "2" 
    } ,
    "innslag": [
    {
        "belop": "-10",
        "dato": "2023-02-20",
        "motBilagsNr": "33",
        "konto":{ "id":1 }
    },
    {
        "belop": "10",
        "dato": "2023-02-20",
        "motBilagsNr": "33",
        "konto":{ "id":1 }
    }]
}
]

How should the controller and html table submits look like?
I want a html page. Not pass the data with JSON through Postman.
Is this possible in the controller?:
@PostMapping("/p")
    public void registerNewWrapper2(List<Wrapper> wrapper) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < wrapper.size(); i++) {
            Bilag bilag = wrapper.get(i).getBilag();
            List<Innslag> innslag = wrapper.get(i).getInnslag();
            bilagService.registerNewBilag(bilag, innslag);
        }

    }

